# Group list by days of week in c

Tags: c

I want to group TV program information from xmltv listings by day of the week. I wrote this code:

```
int epg_show_perchannel( tv_osd_t* osd, int page, station_mgr_t *stationmgr, xmltv_t *xmltv, int channel )
{
if (!page)
    return 0;
if ( xmltv ){
    const int buf_length = 255;
    const int max_num_lines = 15;
    const int num_stations = station_get_num_stations( stationmgr );
    char *old_channel = strdup( xmltv_get_channel( xmltv ) );
    char buf[buf_length+1];
    int cur = 0;
    time_t curtime = time( 0 );
    const char *xmltv_id = 0;

    if (channel > num_stations)  
        channel = 1;
    else if (channel < 1 )
        channel = num_stations;

    if (!(xmltv_id = station_get_xmltv_id( stationmgr, channel-1 ))) 
        xmltv_id = xmltv_lookup_channel( xmltv, station_get_name( stationmgr, channel-1 ));
    xmltv_set_channel( xmltv, xmltv_id);
    xmltv_refresh_withtime( xmltv, curtime );

    /* List header with Channel number + name */
    snprintf(buf, buf_length, "%d Next on [%s] %s:", channel, station_get_channel(stationmgr,channel-1), station_get_name( stationmgr, channel-1));
    tv_osd_list_set_text( osd, cur++, buf );
    tv_osd_list_set_hilight(osd, -1);   

    while ((cur-1) < max_num_lines) {
        xmltv_refresh_withtime( xmltv, curtime );
        /* day of current program*/
        char start_time[50];
        time_t start_timestamp = xmltv_get_start_time( xmltv );
        strftime( start_time, 50, "%A:", localtime( &start_timestamp ) );
        snprintf(buf, buf_length, "%s", start_time, xmltv_get_start_time( xmltv ));
        tv_osd_list_set_text( osd, cur++, buf, 1);

        if (xmltv_get_title( xmltv )) {
            char start_time[50];
            time_t start_timestamp = xmltv_get_start_time( xmltv );
            time_t end_timestamp = xmltv_get_end_time( xmltv );
            strftime( start_time, 50, "%H:%M", localtime( &start_timestamp ) );

            /* starttime of current program + Now showing program */
            snprintf(buf, buf_length, "%s %s", start_time, xmltv_get_title( xmltv ));       
            if (xmltv_get_sub_title( xmltv )){
                strncat(buf," (",buf_length-strlen(buf));  
                strncat(buf,xmltv_get_sub_title( xmltv ),buf_length-strlen(buf));
                strncat(buf,")",buf_length-strlen(buf));  
            }
            tv_osd_list_set_text( osd, cur++, buf, 1);

            if (!xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv )) {
                char end_time[50];
                /* no next program, print endtime of current programme */       
                strftime( end_time, 50, "%H:%M", localtime( &end_timestamp ) );
                snprintf(buf, buf_length, "%s %s", end_time, "");       
                tv_osd_list_set_text( osd, cur++, buf, 1);
            }
        curtime = end_timestamp;**

        } else {
            /* No XMLTV information for this channel */
            tv_osd_list_set_text( osd, cur++, "");
        }

    }
    tv_osd_list_set_lines( osd, cur );
    tv_osd_show_list( osd, 1, 1 );

    xmltv_set_channel(xmltv, old_channel);
    free(old_channel);
    xmltv_refresh( xmltv );

} else {
    tv_osd_list_set_text( osd, 0, "No XMLTV Program Guide information available" );
    tv_osd_list_set_lines( osd, 1 );
    tv_osd_show_list( osd, 1, 1 );
}
return channel;
}
```

This extracts data (and sent to application from xmltv file and create list with 15 line),
but I don't know how group this by days of week:

current output (section of code start with: "while ((cur-1) < max_num_lines) {
"):

```
Sunday:
00:20     Luke, mână rece
Sunday:
02:50     Moartea va fi atât de dulce
Sunday:     
04:45     Interviurile : Matthew Modine Despre Kubrick şi Platoşa de metal
Sunday:     
05:00     Ocean's eleven - Faceţi jocurile!
Sunday:     
22:00     Moartea va fi atât de dulce     
Monday:
00:15     Fără suflare
Monday:     
02:30     Celebritate
```

What I want (not insert name of day after each line, only if day is end):

```
Sunday:
00:20     Luke, mână rece     
02:50     Moartea va fi atât de dulce     
04:45     Interviurile : Matthew Modine Despre Kubrick şi Platoşa de metal     
05:00     Ocean's eleven - Faceţi jocurile!     
22:00     Moartea va fi atât de dulce     
Monday:
00:15     Fără suflare     
02:30     Celebritate     
04:40     Sub influenţa lui: Joan Allen     
05:15     Fără suflare     
22:00     Necruţătorul     
Tuesday:
00:30     Point Blank     
02:25     Mumia
```

Part of xmltv list from extract data:

```
<programme start="20120205220000 +0100" stop="20120205225500 +0100" channel="006.port.hu">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really studied your code.
What you want to do is check if the current day is the same as the previous one and, if it is do not print it.

Initialize the previous day to an invalid value

```
char previousday[500] = "invalid"; /* you might want to use less than 500 chars */
```

and in your loop keep checking

```
if (strcmp(start_time, previousday) != 0) {
    // print, or add to buffer, start_time
    strcpy(previousday, start_time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code, assuming items is sorted by date time, you can do this:

```
last_printed_day = null

foreach item in items
    if item.day != last_printed_day
        print item.day
        last_printed_day = item.day
    end
    print item
end
```

You will probably want to keep track of which actual day was printed last, even if you print the day only formatted as the week day name. That way if you have a data set which has only data for Sundays, you'll still get "Sunday" printed at the start of each day.